# Passing Package Dependencies to Subkernels

Tags: parallelization, packages

Say I have a function `f[x_,...]:=...` in a *.wl-Package form that depends on a bunch of Packages (some other *.wl files), and say I want to call this function `f` several times in parallel. I am currently using a set-up of the following form

```
LaunchKernels[2];
ParallelNeeds["Privatef`",".../f_file.wl"];

ParallelTable[
output[i]=f[i];
,{i,1,10}];
```

where `i` is just supposed to represent a set of parameters. The function `f` itself is of the form

```
BeginPackage["Privatef`"]

f

Begin["fenv`"]
Needs["other Packages"]

some code

End[]

EndPackage[]
```

Now, my problem is that the function `f` is distributed into the different subkernels I generated, though, the other Packages don't seem to load in each subkernel. I have tried to also use `ParallelNeeds` on these additional Packages, but without success. So how do I get Mathematica to load each additional Package that `f` requires in each subkernel that was launched?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are the packages you need in the [`$Path`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Path.html)?

If not, the following may be the simplest solution:

- Create a package file (`.m` or `.wl`) which simply modifies the `$Path`.

  ```
  BeginPackage["PathLoader`"]
  $Path = Join[$Path, {"/path/one", "/path/two"}];
  EndPackage[]
  ```

  The only purpose of the `BeginPackage`/`EndPackage` here is to ensure that `(Parallel)Needs` won't complain about "context not created".
- Put this in a standard location, e.g. `$UserBaseDirectory/Applications/PathLoader.m`.
- Start your session with

  ```
  Needs["PathLoader`"]
  ParallelNeeds["PathLoader`"]
  ```

Now `$Path` will contain all your directories both on the main kernel and on the subkernels.

I use similar (but more complicated) workarounds for `Kernel/init.m` not being loaded on any subkernels.