# Performance issues with Packages within Packages

Tags: performance-tuning, packages

I am currently working on parallelizing a piece of code, as indicated in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/200116/passing-package-dependencies-to-subkernels/200118#200118), which explains the following, rather convoluted, way of evaluating a function; so please bare with me. But irrespective of the parallelization, the following performance issue occurs.

Say I have the functions `fA` and `fB`, both written as a package schematically of the form

```
BeginPackage["packagefA`"]
fA::usage = "some usage."
Begin["envfA`"]
Needs["packagefB`","somepath/packagefB.wl"];

fA[someinput_]:=Module[{input=someinput},
Some codeA
partofoutput=fB[parameter produced by Some codeA];
Some more code
];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

whereas `fB` looks like

```
BeginPackage["packagefB`"]
fB::usage = "some usage."
Begin["envfB`"]

fB[input_]:=Module[{someinput=input},
some code
];
End[]
EndPackage[]
```

So essentially I am just calling function `fB` inside function `fA`. Finally, the function `fA` is then called by some notebook or script (lets call it `interfaceA`), which looks like

```
...
Needs["packagefA`","somepath/packagefA.wl"]
save=fA[someinput];
...
```

Here is the issue I ran into: If I have a separate interface (say `interfaceB`) that **only** calls function `fB`, then the evaluation of `fB` is relatively fast. However, if I run `interfaceA` and look at how long it takes to evaluate the same function `fB` as part of `fA`, then it turns out that this will take significantly longer to evaluate. Why does `fB` not evaluate just as quickly as part of `fA` compared to when I call `fB` directly? Does it have to do with how I load the Package `packagefB` within `packagefA`?

Comment: I don't think your problem can be solved without a working example. p.s. it should be ``Begin["`envfB`"]`` etc.